# AWS Route 53: No targets available with load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I have set up a load balancer in AWS. I need it to run on app.mydomain.com. When I go to Route 53, enter an A record, and click Alias/Yes, the dropdown says "No Targets Available" under "ELB Application load balancers".

I have gotten this to work in the past. What have I forgotten? Why isn't it showing up?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy and paste the ALB domain name to the address field even if doesn’t show up in the list.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors to the page, it took a few hours but the load balancer eventually showed up in the list. It's just slow.